# Javascript Inheritance - "this" keyword losing binding?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, this

I am trying to learn more advanced approaches to inheritance in Javascript, and can't figure out why my inherited object is loosing it's "this" keyword binding in the example code below from Eloquent Javascript.

I've tried calling the take() function for example by using:

```
lantern.take(); // alerts you can not lift
Item.take.call(lantern, "the brass lantern"); // alerts you can not lift
lantern.take.call(this, "the brass lantern"); // alerts you can not lift
```

Neither of these binds this.name to lantern though? What am I missing/not understanding in my approach to calling the methods defined in my objects prototype? Thank you.

```
function forEachIn(object, action) {
  for (var property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property))
      action(property, object[property]);
  }
}

function clone(object) {
  function OneShotConstructor(){}
  OneShotConstructor.prototype = object;
  return new OneShotConstructor();
}

Object.prototype.create = function() {
  var object = clone(this);
  if (typeof object.construct == "function")
    object.construct.apply(object, arguments);
  return object;
};

Object.prototype.extend = function(properties) {
  var result = clone(this);
  forEachIn(properties, function(name, value) {
    result[name] = value;
  });
  return result;
};

var Item = {
  construct: function(name) {
    this.name = name;
  },
  inspect: function() {
    alert("it is ", this.name, ".");
  },
  kick: function() {
    alert("klunk!");
  },
  take: function() {
    alert("you can not lift ", this.name, ".");
  }
};

var lantern = Item.create("the brass lantern");
lantern.kick(); // alerts klunk
```

Comment: Don't overwrite `Object.prototype.create` with non-standard behaviour.

Comment: Don't put anything in `Object.prototype` period

Comment: @Bergi: You're thinking of `Object.create`. There's no standard `create` on `Object.prototype`.

Comment: @user1689607: Oh, right. Still, Esailija is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike `console.log`, [`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.alert) takes only one argument. You'd need to concat the strings:

```
alert("you can not lift " + this.name + ".");
```

With that, both `lantern.take();` and `Item.take.call(lantern);` - which are equivalent - will alert "you can not lift the brass lantern.", while your third example depends on the value of the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in the current execution. Btw, your `take` function does not take an argument.

Comment: Wow! Thank you. Yes, the book used a "made up" print function which I edited to "alert" for testing. That is the simplest answer ever! Thank you!